# Is proof by modular arithmetic appropriate in this syntax?

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have a question which asks:

Prove there are **no** integer solutions for the equation:

$$4x = y^2 +1 $$

To prove, lets take $\pmod4$ of both sides, such that:

$$ 4x\pmod4 = (y^2 +1)\pmod4$$

$$ \implies 4x(mod 4)= (y^2(mod (4)) + 1(mod(4)))\pmod4$$

By looking at the $LHS$ of the equation we see that $4x \pmod4 = 0$, $\forall{x}$

By looking at the $RHS$ we have:

$$y^2\pmod 4= 1$$ for all odd y

$$y^2\pmod 4= 0$$ for all even y.

and
$$1 \pmod4= 1$$.

Therefore,  the equation does not hold it's equality for all integers $x$ and $y$.

Is this a valid proof?

Comment: It is definitely not my preferred notation, but the proof is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's the same idea of writing

$$x = \frac{y^2+1}{4}$$ and noticing that, if $y=2k$ then $$x = k^2 + \frac{1}{4}$$ and if $y = 2k+1$ then $$x= k+2k + \frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a valid proof, but you should really carry it through at the end and say clearly why this proves the result.
$$y^2+1 \equiv \begin{cases} 0+1=1, &y\text{ even } \\ 1+1=2, &y\text{ odd}\end{cases}$$
so that the left-hand side is congruent to $0$ modulo $4$, while the right-hand side cannot be.